# Bipass Windows 8 introduction screen for new user

Tags: windows-8, boot

I was wondering if it possible to disable the new user introduction screens for Windows 8 (it opens by saying "Hi" and "We are setting things up for you".

Now I am aware this is the process that the OS uses to sort of keep users attention while it is running background processes to set the user profile up and take all the necessary info from servers and what not, BUT is there a way in which I can customise the appearance of this Mask if you will, to show maybe a welcome message of my own or one from my company so that the IT team don't have to sit through endless run throughs of this "Hi here's how windows 8 works" message screens?

Comment: Yes; Its possible; The simplest solution is you use deployable .wim images. You won't be able to customize the message through.  You can also just disable the feature that teaches you how Windows 8 works, its also much easier to do this, if you move directly to 8.1

Comment: Ah so this would mean id need to create new .wim images for each individual message?

Comment: I just said;  You won't be able to change the message.  What you can do is deploy an image where that message is configured not to be displayed.  The standard .wim image used by the installer is configured to do that.

Comment: Ah well I thought you meant create and image with a message on and use that instead then change the image every so often that's what I thought you meant